# mina gem deploy through gateway

Tags: ruby, deployment, apache-mina

I am using the mina gem to deploy.
I have to go through a gateway in order to connect to my server.
I know that capistrano enables it.

Does any one know this config in mina?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe mina supports this; certainly, [the source code](https://github.com/nadarei/mina/blob/master/lib/mina/ssh_helpers.rb) doesn't indicate such an option. I was experimenting with using the `set :ssh_options, ''` syntax, but mina appends `-t` to the end of the command chain, which then gets sent to the wrong server. Considered changing the mina code, but it's probably simpler to shift the gateway connection to your local ssh client itself, and possibly to use the `set :forward_agent, true` command. To do such, you'd set something like this in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host finaldestination.example.com
    ProxyCommand ssh user@gateway.example.com nc %h 22
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Testing using my localhost as a gateway seems to show this as workable.

Hope this helps - although I realise it isn't exactly what you were asking. :)